# TimescaleDB Continuous Aggregates WITH NO DATA not working

Tags: postgresql, timescaledb, continuous-aggregates

I use this query to create a continuous aggregate on one of my hypertables:

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW logschema."aggregateValveMovementDaily" WITH (timescaledb.continuous) AS
    SELECT "ID",
           time_bucket('1 day', "hour") as "day",
           COUNT("ID") as "messageCount",
           min("movement") as "movement_min"
    FROM logschema."movementHourly"
    GROUP BY "ID", "day"
WITH NO DATA;
```

But the View is populated with data which is exactly what I don't want because we have alot of data which we want to migrate manually.
How can I just get an empty table which I can later fill with data?

Comment: Is it actually filling in data, or are you getting results due to real-time aggregation https://docs.timescale.com/timescaledb/latest/how-to-guides/continuous-aggregates/real-time-aggregates/

Comment: its actually filling in, I added the data manually with a timestamp from last week and it still filled the data into the table

Comment: I think you'll need to actually disable the real time aggregation to achieve it:
`ALTER MATERIALIZED VIEW logschema."aggregateValveMovementDaily" set (timescaledb.materialized_only = true);`

Comment: Thanks that helped alot, its working now!